# How to install FreeBSD 11.2 on my LinuxMint 18.3 machine?

Tags: linux-mint, freebsd

I got Toshiba C640 i3 Machine, 2GB Ram with LinuxMint18.3 installed on whole drive 500GB. I recently downloaded FreeBSD 11.2 ISO DVD and wanted to install it as dual boot. So that I can slowly learn FreeBSD along working LMint.

Where to find official documentation to partition my drive according to the requirement for FreeBSD to install on top of Linux machine keeping the grub boot loader intact?

For FreeBSD with Xfce or lxde desktop env, is  2GB RAM good enough? And where to find the documentation to install LXDE for FreeBSD

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK5075GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  498GB  498GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      498GB   500GB  2001MB  extended
 5      498GB   500GB  2001MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: To learn a new operating system, I would advice running it in a virtual machine first.

Comment: Is there is no other option to have it like a dual boot? I really do want to have a dual boot for this and test it, @Kusalananda

Comment: I suggested setting up a virtual machine, because it's simpler and does not impact on you existing host operating system (no need to resize partitions etc.)

Answer (score 3):

As @Kusalananda pointed out, a virtual machine (VM) would be your best bet. Virtual Box runs FreeBSD but I have had problems with the drivers for shared folders (though I think that was fixed sometime this year). I have Windows 10 on my laptop with different FreeBSD virtual machines that I use. GhostBSD is a nice stable GUI 'distro' that I use for mucking around and I have a non-X FreeBSD image for testing builds and things. You could set up the same thing in Mint.

Something especially handy about using a VM is that when you do run into issues, you switch out of the VM, load a browser in your host OS and research your problem. When I have set up dual boot machines, I have often run into a situation where I need an answer and can't get to a browser because, well, my OS is dead.

Comment: I do want to have FreeBSD as the only OS on my laptop, but at this moment, I want to try it as dual boot so that I can try few software which are necessary and play how to use that and make a move to freeBSD fully. I haven't tried VM yet and couldn't get will it create new drive or is it just an pseudo creation of drive to have like an application working. Do have to check documentation to try that..

Comment: @user1900238 A virtual machine's hard disk is simply a file on the host computer. Install VirtualBox and give it a try.

Comment: Install Oracle Virtual Box through your package manager and follow the wizards in the GUI. There are many Virtual Box walk-throughs on the Internet. Download the ISO (https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) and attach it as a CD drive. The FreeBSD ISO will start an installer that is very similar to the Debian installer. After it's complete, detach the ISO and restart the VM. If you want a GUI download GhostBSD: https://ghostbsd.org/. I'm not sure the status of another GUI called Project Trident: http://www.project-trident.org/. Another non-GUI distro is TrueOS: https://trueos.org/